# C# remove children added by loop

Tags: c#

I am adding children by loop to the Main grid. But how do I remove them? I want to remove only the children I added each time the function was called and then add the new ones.

```
void flcl_Selection(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        //remove children here     
        for (int i = 0; i < e.MyFirstString.Count; i ++)
        {
            LabelCountry lbl = new LabelCountry((string)e.MyFirstString[i]);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(lbl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the plattform/framework you are using.

Comment: Do you have any of your own thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, to overcome this requirement, yourself?

Comment: I have tried to give each lbl name and then remove by it. But I did not mentioned that because it may be confusing. MatthiasG answer is exactly what i looked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to store the added elements to be able to remove them. E.g.:

```
private List<LabelCountry> addedElements = new List<LabelCountry>();

void flcl_Selection(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    //remove old items
    foreach(LabelCountry element in addedElements)
    {
        MainGrid.Children.Remove(element);
    }
    addedElements.Clear();
    // add new items
    for (int i = 0; i < e.MyFirstString.Count; i ++)
    {
        LabelCountry lbl = new LabelCountry((string)e.MyFirstString[i]);
        addedElements.Add(lbl)
        MainGrid.Children.Add(lbl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<object> _addedItems = new List<object>();

void flcl_Selection(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    //remove children here     
    foreach(var item in _addedItems)
    {
        MainGrid.Children.Remove(item);
    }
    _addedItems = new List<object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < e.MyFirstString.Count; i ++)
    {
        LabelCountry lbl = new LabelCountry((string)e.MyFirstString[i]);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(lbl);
        _addedItems.Add(lbl);
    }
}
```